# Does $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\frac{a_n}{n}=0$ implies that $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\frac{a_n}{n^t}<\infty$ for some $0<t<1$?

Tags: calculus, limits

Suppose that $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\frac{a_n}{n}=0$, where $\{a_n\}$ is a seqeunce of positive integers with $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}a_n=+\infty$. Can we get that $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\frac{a_n}{n^t}<+\infty$ for some $0<t<1$? I worry that there exists $\{a_n\}$ such that $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\frac{a_n}{n}=0$ but $\{\frac{a_n}{n^t}\}$ is oscillating for any $0<t<1$ and therefore its limit doesn't exist. Can anyone give some comments on it? Thanks.

Comment: What about $a_n = n/\ln(n)$?

Comment: @Martin Thanks. It is fasle.